# H2 driver can't find/create a table

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, h2, sqlexception

I have the following query that I'm trying to execute against a local/embedded H2 DB:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO animals ( animal_name, animal_type_id ) VALUES ( 'Dog', 34 )";
sqlExecutor.doSQL(sql);

// SQLExecutor.java
public class SQLExecutor {
    private static final String DRIVER_CLASS = "org.h2.Driver";
    private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:h2:~/.myapp/data/myapp_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";
    private static final String DB_USER = "myuser";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "mypasswd";

    public void doSQL(String sql) {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preppedStatement = null;
        ConnectionPool connectionPool = new ConnectionPool(DRIVER_CLASS, CONNECTION_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

        try {
            connection = connectionPool.borrow();
            preppedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(statement.getStatement());

            preppedStatement.executeUpdate();

            connection.commit();
        } catch(Throwable throwable) {
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(throwable));
            throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
        } finally {
            // Close result set, prepped statement, return connection, etc.
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ANIMALS" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO animals ( animal_name, animal_type_id ) VALUES ( ?, ? );  [42102-173]
    at net.myapp.core.SQLExecutor.doSQL(SQLExecutor.java:23)
```

Line 23 of `SQLExecutor` is:

```
preppedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(statement.getStatement());
```

I was told that H2 will create a table if none existed, so I'm confused as to why its telling me that the table isn't found - shouldn't it just be created? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be a magic if tables are created yourself.

Comment: H2 Will create table if it does not exists, or will it create **DATABASE** if provided in connection url does not exist? I bet on the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2 can create database if not exist. But you need to create tables by yourself using SQL
Go ahead with

CREATE TABLE animals
(
animal_type_id int,
animal_name varchar(255)
);

Comment: Ahhh, duh! Can't believe I missed that one. All work and no play makes Ticketmonster a dumb coder. All work and no play...